# Selecting a division based on what division it using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div class = ui-dialog-abc ui-dialog-xyz>
<div id = "sheet1abc">
</div>
</div>

<div class = ui-dialog-abc ui-dialog-xyz>
<div id = "sheet1xyz">
</div>
</div>

<div class = ui-dialog-abc ui-dialog-xyz>
<div id ="sheet2foo">
</div>
</div>

<div class = ui-dialog-abc ui-dialog-xyz>
</div>
```

Can I select a div based on what div it contains? I want to make the `div` containing the `div` whose `id` contains `sheet1` visible or hidden.

Answer (score 5):

If I've understood you correctly, you are looking to select the `div` that is a parent of a `div` with an `id` beginning with "sheet1".

If that's correct, you can do the following:

`$("div[id^=sheet1]")`

That will select all `div` elements with an `id` beginning with "sheet1". You can then loop through the set of elements using `each` and get the `parent` of each element to access the parent `div`.

Once you have the parent `div`, you can show/hide it using `show` or `hide`.

See an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGYHy/) in which I alert the `id` of the each matching parent `div`.

**Update**

If the child `div` you are looking for is not a direct child of the ancestor `div`, you can use `parent().closest('div')` to climb the DOM tree to find the first ancestor `div` of the `div` with your `id`.

The question asks to get the "`div` containing the `div`...", so this method will get the first ancestor `div`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGYHy/1/), in which the child `div` is contained within a table.

Comment: The wording is generic, "contains" implies any level, although I agree the example implies direct parent. Not sure what the difference between `.parent().hide()` and your code (other than yours being longer and slightly less efficient), since you hide all of them as well, and parent.hide is just as flexible, if I wanted to hide only some, I would add a filter...

Comment: Agreed. If I get a minute I'll update the answer to work with any descendant element instead of a direct child.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').has('div[id="sheet1abc"]').text();
$('div').has('div[id="sheet1xyz"]').text();
```

Comment: Would probably use `:has()`, sizzle might be able to optimise, but this answer is indeed a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Grab all divs whose ids contain 'sheet1', then grab their closest containing div:

```
$('div[id*=sheet1]').map(function() {
    return $(this).parents('div:first')[0] 
});
```